# The meaning of a continuous distributional-valued function?

Tags: continuity, distribution-theory

Can anyone teach me the means of the following?

$$ f(t,x,v) \in C(\mathbb{R}_+; \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n_x \times \mathbb{R}^n_v)).$$

where $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n_x \times \mathbb{R}^n_v)$ is the space of distributions on $\mathbb{R}^n_x \times \mathbb{R}^n_v$.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should probably ask a more specific question. Which parts of this are you having trouble understanding? Do you have the relevant definitions?

Comment: What do you know about the topologies on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and on $\mathcal{D}'(\bullet)$?

Comment: @md2perpe $\mathbb{R}_+$ is equipped with the usual topology and $\mathcal{D}'(\cdot)$ is equipped with the distributional topology induced by seminorms...? That's all the information from Villani's book.

Comment: So what is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @md2perpe Well, I was a little confused with the other spaces =(, since originally $f(t,x,v) \in C(\mathbb{R}_+; \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n_x \times \mathbb{R}^n_v)) \bigcap L_{\text{loc}}^\infty(\mathbb{R}_+; L^2((1+E) dvdx)) \bigcap L^2_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}_+; H^1_v(\mathbb{R}^n_x \times \mathbb{R}^n_v))$. Thank you for clarifying it for me!

Comment: @Karl I think I was a bit confused. Thank you for your attention.